# Upload speed to Google Cloud machine is 1.1Gbps

Tags: google-cloud-platform, bandwidth, upload

I use GCP VMs very often. Create and delete once chunk of work is done. I need to upload large data file every time.

Consistently it uploads at 1.1Gbps average speed. Internet connection is 80Gbps (verified). Machine is in local to me region (europe-west4).

Is Google throttling connections? Can i make it faster?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/5-steps-to-better-gcp-network-performance?hl=ml

> Outbound or egress traffic from a virtual machine is subject to maximum network egress throughput caps. These caps are dependent on the number of vCPUs that a virtual machine instance has. Each core is subject to a 2 Gbits/second (Gbps) cap for peak performance. Each additional core increases the network cap, up to a theoretical maximum of 16 Gbps for each virtual machine.